# Using .include? to prevent duplicates

Tags: ruby

A bit confused as to how I can use `.include?` on this to prevent a duplicate item from joining the list.

I'm first told to append an item to the list.

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item
end
```

Then I need to use `.include?` to prevent duplicates. My attempt:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item
  list.include?(item)
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use a set instead of array http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: @NullSoulException Set doesn't provide guarantees about order like Array does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the code in a method you have to take into account that Ruby passes arguments by value, not by reference. Why in the first case this does seems to work, I don't know, could be a question by itself. So I ended the name of the first method with ! (in place) but not the other two.

I did some benchmarking with three different methods and the include? solution clearly wins. Putting the initial value of the array takes time but all the solutions have to do this so you can discard this.

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

def add_item1!(item, list)
  list << item unless list.include?(item)
end

def add_item2(item, list)
  list |= [item]
end

def add_item3(item, list)
  set = Set.new(list)
  set << item
  list = set.to_a
end

array1 = [3,2,1,4]
add_item1!(2, array1) # [3, 2, 1, 4]
add_item1!(5, array1) # [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

array2 = [3,2,1,4]
array2 = add_item2(2, array2) # [3, 2, 1, 4]
array2 = add_item2(5, array2) # [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

array3 = [3,2,1,4]
array3 = add_item3(2, array3) # [3, 2, 1, 4]
array3 = add_item3(5, array3) # [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

TESTS = 100000
Benchmark.bmbm do |results|
  results.report("unless not new") {TESTS.times {array1 = [3,2,1,4];add_item1!(2, array1) }}
  results.report("unless new")     {TESTS.times{array1 = [3,2,1,4];add_item1!(5, array1) }}
  results.report("|= not new")     {TESTS.times{array2 = [3,2,1,4];array2 = add_item2(2, array2) }}
  results.report("|= new")         {TESTS.times{array2 = [3,2,1,4];array2 = add_item2(5, array2) }}
  results.report("Set not new")    {TESTS.times{array3 = [3,2,1,4];array3 = add_item3(2, array3) }}
  results.report("Set new")        {TESTS.times{array3 = [3,2,1,4];array3 = add_item3(5, array3) }}
end

#                      user     system      total        real
# unless not new   0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.027002)
# unless new       0.047000   0.000000   0.047000 (  0.052003)
# |= not new       0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.118007)
# |= new           0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.126007)
# Set not new      0.358000   0.000000   0.358000 (  0.354020)
# Set new          0.359000   0.000000   0.359000 (  0.364021)
```

Comment: Thnx for accepting rSV, I asked the question about the passing by reference at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506596/why-this-ruby-method-passes-its-argument-by-reference

Comment: Good answer, but it should be noted that you'd get different results if you were adding several items to the list. In particular, the setup cost to create a set would soon pay dividends. Depending on the application, adding with abandon and then `uniq`ifying may be another possibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it this way:

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item unless list.include?(item)
end
```

In the code above, `#include?` is called *before* adding the item to the list.  If the item is already in the list, `#include?` returns true and the code that adds the item to the list will be skipped.

Comment: something like this should work too =>>  list |= [item]

Comment: I completely forgot about `unless`. However it returns `nil` instead of say `orange` as a item.

Comment: Then you can use an if/else statement to do something special when the item is included.

Comment: Please don't add requirements after asking the question.  The code I provided prevents duplicates as requested.

Comment: I just didn't know using the `unless` made it return `nil`.  Wasn't intending on adding a "requirement".

Answer (score 0):

Ir you only want to maintains your array and you don't know if the element was added you could do this

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list = list | [item]
end
```

Here you can find an example.

```
2.2.1 :001 > [1,2]
 => [1, 2] 
2.2.1 :002 > [1,2] | [1]
 => [1, 2] 
2.2.1 :003 > [1,2] | [1,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.2.1 :004 >
```

> ary | other_ary → new_ary
>
> Set Union — Returns a new array by joining ary with other_ary, excluding > any duplicates and preserving the order from the original array.

But if you want to know if the element was rejected you can do

```
def add_item!(item, list)
  list << item unless list.include?(item)
end
```