# Why this Ruby method passes it's argument by reference

Tags: ruby, parameters, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I answered on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505837/using-include-to-prevent-duplicates/31506338#31506338) question and stumbled on something strange.
Ruby passes its arguments by value, the variables itself are references though.
So why the first methods seems to pass its parameter by reference ?

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

def add_item1!(item, list)
  list << item unless list.include?(item)
end

def add_item2(item, list)
  list |= [item]
end

def add_item3(item, list)
  set = Set.new(list)
  set << item
  list = set.to_a
end

array1 = [3,2,1,4]
add_item1!(5, array1)
p array1 # [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

array2 = [3,2,1,4]
add_item2(5, array2) 
p array2 # [3, 2, 1, 4]

array3 = [3,2,1,4]
add_item3(5, array3)
p array3 # [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-confusing term is [Call by Object-Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing): **the *original* object (and *not* a copy/clone/duplicate) is passed.**

> The semantics of call by sharing differ from call by reference in that *assignments to function arguments within the function aren't visible to the caller*

In Ruby **re-assigning [local] parameters has *no effect* on the caller** as it does *not* use Call by Reference.

In this example code it clearly does *not* have Call by Reference semantics; or the 2nd and 3rd cases, which assign back to the *local* variable but otherwise *do not modify the original object*, would work like the 1st.

On a 'lower level' the implementation is Call by Value [of a Reference] - that is, internally Ruby uses pointers and whatnot - which is why sometimes the overloaded phrase "call by reference" is used, often forgetting the "by value" part .. and leading to this sort of confusion.

---

```
def add_item1!(item, list)
  # MUTATES the list object, which is the original object passed
  # (there is no copy/clone/duplication that occurred)
  list << item unless list.include?(item)
end

def add_item2(item, list)
  # this creates a NEW list and re-assigns it to the parameter
  # re-assigning to a local parameter does not affect the caller
  # the original list object is not modified
  list |= [item]
end

def add_item3(item, list)
  set = Set.new(list)
  set << item
  # this creates a NEW list from set and re-assigns it to the parameter
  # re-assigning to a local parameter does not affect the caller
  # the original list object is not modified
  list = set.to_a
end
```

Comment: I see, I should have used .replace to modify the original object